# How do I implement ArangoDB HTTP API authentication on DC/OS cluster

Tags: arangodb, pyarango

When using a single arangodb instance, I've used the root user and a password to authenticate my pyArango connection in my application.
I tried to do the same thing with my cluster, but i couldn't.
Is there a better way?